# Open page in document library by default brower

Tags: 2010, document-library

I want to open page in document library by brower.
I have a SharePoint 2010 system.

I have 2 web application port 8080 and 8083.

I configed the default open behavior for browser-enabled documents (Office Web Apps) like guide https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837425(v=office.14).aspx#bkmk_set__sc but only web application port 8080 is OK and web application port 8083 is not OK.

I don't know why?

Comment: Kindly check this article......https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837425.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can check the Feature **"Open Documents in Client Applications by Default"** is active or not at site collection level. If it active please try to disable the feature.

1. In site collection, go site actions and Site Settings.
2. In the Site Settings page, under Site Collection Administration, choose Site Collection Features.
3. deactivate the feature which is shown in the image below

[image]